# React Loading Msg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I am working on a react app that shortens a URL after a button is clicked. I am having a hard time figuring out the best logic to do so. The loading message does not show then when I click the button. The loading button appears and then disappears when the message loads.

The current behavior with the code below is the following.

1. When it renders "Loading..." does not show.
2. I click my "Shorten it" button and "Loading..." shows.
3. The shortened url appears below the "Loading..." button.

Shorten.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Shorten = () => {
    const [shortLink, setShortLink] = useState(null);
    const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(false);
    const [input, setInput] = useState('example.org/very/long/link.html');
    const url = "https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten?url=";

    const fullUrl = (url.concat(input));
    console.log(fullUrl);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(fullUrl)
        .then(res => {
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            setShortLink(data.result.short_link);
            // setIsPending(false);
        })
    }, [fullUrl ])
    // input
    // value={input} 
    const loadMsg = () =>{
        setIsPending(true);
    }
    return (
        <main>
            <section className="purple-card">
                <input  onInput={e => setInput(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Shorten a link here..." className="shorten-input"/>
                <button className="shorten-it" onClick={() => loadMsg()}>Shorten It!</button> 
            </section>
            <section className="white-card">
                {isPending && <div className="loading-text">Loading...</div>}
                {shortLink && <div className="shorten-text">{shortLink}</div>}
                <hr></hr>
                <button className="shorten-it" >Copy</button> 
            </section>
        </main>
    );
}
 
export default Shorten;
```

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be a few issues here. The reason the loading message and the shortened URL display at the same time is that their render conditions are not mutually exclusive. Fixing that is as simple as not showing the shortened URL while the component is loading.

Also something that can cause issues is that the "Shorten It!" button does not control actually performing the shortening action, it just sets the loading (pending) state to `true`. The shortening action runs whenever the input's value changes. Basically the loading state and the shortening action are fairly independent of each other.

To fix this you should only run the shortening action when the user clicks the button and at that point set the `isPending` state to `true` at the same time (then set back to `false` when done).

Instead of `useEffect`, you can just use a function that gets called when the button is clicked.

For example:

```
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";

const Shorten = () => {
    const [shortLink, setShortLink] = useState(null);
    const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(false);
    const [input, setInput] = useState('example.org/very/long/link.html');

    const shortenUrl = useCallback(() => {
        setIsPending(true);
        const baseUrl = "https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten?url=";
        const fullUrl = baseUrl + input;
        fetch(fullUrl)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                setShortLink(data.result.short_link)
            })
            .finally(() => setIsPending(false));
    }, [input]);

    return (
        <main>
            <section className="purple-card">
                <input  onInput={e => setInput(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Shorten a link here..." className="shorten-input"/>
                <button className="shorten-it" onClick={shortenUrl}>Shorten It!</button> 
            </section>
            <section className="white-card">
                {isPending && <div className="loading-text">Loading...</div>}
                {!isPending && shortLink && <div className="shorten-text">{shortLink}</div>}
                <hr></hr>
                <button className="shorten-it" >Copy</button> 
            </section>
        </main>
    );
}

export default Shorten;
```

Alternatively, to make the loading/result more clearing mutually exclusive, you can define a single variable with a value of either the loading message, the result URL, or nothing. For example:

```
const result = useMemo(() => {
    if (isPending) {
        return <div className="loading-text">Loading...</div>;
    }
    if (shortLink) {
        return <div className="shorten-text">{shortLink}</div>;
    }
    return null;
}, [isPending, shortLink]);
```

Then render like so:

```
<section className="white-card">
    {result}
</section>
```

Comment: Call `setIsPending(false)` in the `.finally` block of the promise chain so it happens regardless of resolved or rejected promise from `fetch`.

Comment: @DrewReese good thinking. I'm more of an `async`/`await` man myself so I'm not as familiar with the `.then` style.

Comment: It's the Promise-chain equivalent of the `try/catch/finally` that would be used with `async/await`.